# Wireguard not working with double-hop VPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, wireguard

I have this double-hop VPN setup that was working until a few months ago. Recently I found enough time to dig around and see what went wrong, but I am stumped, so I'm looking for some help if someone knows what to do.

Essentially, I have a sort of VPN gateway made with OpenVPN (guide: https://github.com/mr-canoehead/vpn_client_gateway/wiki/Installation-Guide) which has my Raspberry Pi permanently connected to Mullvad and I just choose a location.

I've setup a WireGuard connection which would create the double-hop and opened a port forward on my router. Then I connect to WireGuard, which in turns means I am connected through OpenVPN as well.

I did some testing and this is what I found out:

1. Double-hop connection works if I connect from within LAN, i.e. when my phone or laptop are on WiFi.
2. I can't connect to WireGuard when I'm connecting from WAN, i.e. when my phone is on 4G connection (handshake failed).
3. I **can** connect to my WireGuard and it works fine if I instruct OpenVPN Gateway to drop its VPN connection.

This led me to believe it is a routing problem. I've looked into it, but can't find the right solution. I've added the following to my OpenVPN conf file:

```
#Exception for the LAN
route 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.1.1
route 170.178.190.196 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
route 10.0.1.1 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

I can't remember what the 1st line was for, I believe it was something along the lines of what I'm trying to do now.
The 2nd line is for DDNS tool, so it could check what my IP was outside of VPN connection and report it back to Cloudflare.
The 3rd one should be to make LAN devices available when connected from outside, but I'm not sure.

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure I just need to fix something here, since I have cases where it works, as described above. It seems to me that when the OpenVPN connection is active, WireGuard can't see my Raspberry, because it's now on different IP due to VPN connection. I could be wrong, though.

If I need to post any additional information from my configuration, please let me know!

Comment: I have not tried with the VPN above. You might see if Wireguard or your VPN app have NAT Traversal settings. That is how I get around double NAT when using Phone or Internet USB key.

Comment: Any suggestion how I could check that? I've tried to find it for myself for a couple of days, but with no luck... I'm afraid I'm not that well versed in networking (yet), so any help would be more than welcomed!

Comment: If you cannot find the NAT Traversal setting, it may not be able to navigate a double NAT.

Comment: I already have these two rules in firewall to make the VPNs play nicely with each other (at least it worked before), so I assumed NAT traversal might be related to the "nat" part of the rules:
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun-outgoing -j MASQUERADE

Now I'm not sure if that's related, but thought I'd mention. Btw, tun-outgoing is my VPN gateway